# run bash script doesn't work alias command in zsh

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, alias

I use zsh in centos. And I want running some shell script. Like this.

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

# something ..

source ./aliases-file.sh
```

**aliases-file.sh**

```
alias test=ls
alias test2=cat
```

I run `./script.sh`, the alias has not been applied to the current session.
how can I work this?

Comment: The source statement goes before the # something.

Comment: I tried, but it did not matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `script.sh` it is executed in a subshell and your aliases won't propagate up to the calling shell (or current session as you refer to it). You need to source script.sh itself: `source script.sh`. That will cause the commands to be run in your current shell and the aliases will become visible.

Side note: for portability reasons you should consider using `.` instead of `source` as the former is POSIX standard while the latter is a *bashism*.